# InputStream from a pipe to another process remains blocked

Tags: java, pipe

I'm trying to do some basic piping in Java. I wrote a very simple program for testing, but the code keeps getting blocked in the while loop because there seems to be no input from stdout of cat. Which part did I do wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception{
    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat");
    PrintStream out=new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream());
    Scanner in=new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
    out.println("hello");
    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you stop cat. Do you get anything printed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `PrintStream` doesn't flush automatically.  You can either construct it using `new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream(), true);` to enable autoFlush or add a call to `out.flush()` after your `out.println("hello");` to manually flush the string after writing to it.  Either results in `in` reading in what you printed to `out`.

Answer (score 0):

in.hasNextLine() requires end of line, this may be the problem. Try if following works

```
    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
    for (int c;(c=in.read())!= -1;) {
        System.out.print((char)c);
    }
```